# Exception java - почему

Tags: java, исключения

Есть код:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LogRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String logs = getTextFromFile("\\home\\qa-1\\Logs.txt");

        Pattern regexLog = Pattern.compile("(^.{15}).(Activity:.)");

        for (String lg : severalLogs(logs)) {
            Matcher m = regexLog.matcher(lg);

            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(lg.replaceAll(String.valueOf(regexLog), "$1$2"));
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getTextFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    }

    public static String[] severalLogs(String text) {
        return text.split("\\n");
    }
}
```

выдает

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \home\qa-1\Logs.txt
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:215)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:369)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:415)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3207)
    at LogRead.getTextFromFile(LogRead.java:25)
    at LogRead.main(LogRead.java:10)
```

я так понимаю неверный путь к файлу. Но путь то верный. У меня убунту. В чем причина?

Comment: разделители пути в другую сторону(т.е. вместо `\\home\\qa-1\\Logs.txt` используйте `/home/qa-1/Logs.txt`)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло

Answer (score 7):

```
 String logs = getTextFromFile("\\home\\qa-1\\Logs.txt");
```

Всегда думал что в линукс системах слеши другие:

```
 String logs = getTextFromFile("/home/qa-1/Logs.txt");
```

А правильно и кошерно, путь указывать так, чтобы было платформо независимо:

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");

// inserts correct file path separator on *nix and Windows
// works on *nix
// works on Windows
java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(home, "my", "app", "dir")
boolean directoryExists = java.nio.file.Files.exists(path);
```